# Detect class of clicked image getting wrong output

Tags: jquery, function, class, onclick, target

I am trying to figure out how to detect what image I've clicked on by using jQuery. When I click on an image using the code I have right now it gives me IMG as an output but is not the output what I've been looking for. If I click on the image with the class **.i**, it should give me **.i** as output. Now I am getting IMG as output.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper i">
      <img src="media/i-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
      I-formatie
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper u">
      <img src="media/u-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
      U-formatie
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="img-wrapper o">
        <img src="media/o-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      O-formatie
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".i,.u,.o").click(function(event){
  $("#S-formatie").html("Triggered by a " + event.target.nodeName + " element.");
});
```

Comment: Where is the element `#S-formatie`?

Comment: @JohnR in my code, but not here above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.target is the actual thing you clicked on.

event.currentTarget is the thing with the event listener attached to it.

```js
$(".i,.u,.o").click(function(event) {
  $("#S-formatie").html("Triggered by a " + event.currentTarget.classList[1] + " element.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="S-formatie"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper i">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    I-formatie
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper u">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    U-formatie
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper o">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    O-formatie
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, but how do I know on what image I've clicked on? Because now the output is: DIV

Comment: I've modified the event handler to print the second class in the classlist of the element that has the event attached to it. What are you hoping to do? It may be easier to just have a separate event handler registered to each of the target elements

Comment: This method is not recommended as it relies on the order of the classes...

Answer (score 1):

> If I click on the image with the class .i, it should give me .i as output.

To achieve your requirement, use classList attribute in the element as below code snippets.

**Code snippets:** (Note: It will work for click on `div` and `img` element )

```js
$(".i,.u,.o").click(function(event) {      
  $("#S-formatie").html("Triggered by a " + this.classList[1] + " element.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper i">
      <img src="media/i-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    I-formatie
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper u">
      <img src="media/u-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    U-formatie
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="img-wrapper o">
      <img src="media/o-formatie.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    O-formatie
  </div>
</div>
<div id="S-formatie"></div>
```